# How to get sculpting to stop mirroring?

Tags: sculpting

I have a model I am trying to sculpt on and the only modifier I have is multi-res. I am trying to sculpt, and when I do it keeps mirroring. In the picture, you see two strokes, but I only want one stroke. [image]

Answer (score 5):

In the tool panel, <kbd>T</kbd> if it is not open find *Symmetry/ Lock* and disable mirror there. It is directly under Dynotopo.

[image]