# i am using sculpt mode in blender but when i use draw format in it it uses draw from both sides of the plane how can i draw it from one side?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, sculpting

As  my draw format of *Sculpt Mode* is working in dual form, please recommend a solution. I want to create something on only one side of my object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get sculpting to stop mirroring?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53106/how-to-get-sculpting-to-stop-mirroring)

Comment: @Timaroberts Until the OP comments, I don't think it's clear if they are talking about mirroring or backfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Try this option, if I understood the problem ...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand right, you have a mirror lock on. While in *Sculpt Mode*, key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*, then go to the *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Tools tab > Symmetry/lock dropdown* and turn off all of the *Mirror:* values.

[image]